# How can I let PHPMyAdmin accepts foreign language?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

In my website that I am building, when the user enters any value with different language, the value is stored in the database as characters

To illustrate the problem:

```
ID       StudnetName
10001    &#1575;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;
```

I tried to use meta tag but it didn't work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar"/>
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are UTF-8 codes.

use:

```
<META http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Should I use it after <head> tag

Comment: I would recommend to you to check on phpMyAdmin if the db encoding is set to MySQL collation "utf-8-general-ci"

Comment: I put it inside the head tag but it didn't work. I want to use Arabic language. Through my reading about meta tag, UTF-8 doesn't accept arabic language, what should I replace it with?

Comment: UTF-8 includes Arabic language for sure.  maybe you have the '&#1575;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;' string saved in utf-8, that is saving the string encoded by mistake. if you save it just احمد in utf-8 there won't be any problem. 

Why do you have it encoded in the first place?

Comment: I did what you told me and still doesn't work
This is a picture for the PHPMyAdmin that I use
http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/308/phpp.jpg
As you see, the collation that I use is UTF-8 unicode

Comment: When you lok at the data in this field, do you see `احمد` or `&#1575;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;` ?

Comment: No I see &#1575;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583;

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed the problem by using the following statement:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $con);
```

I also changed the collation for each field to

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Thanks